# Disable the wireless network adapter in arch

Tags: networking, arch-linux

I am running arch on a notebook, but I do not need the wireless connection. Nevertheless the adapter is continuously running, even if it is not necessary. Is it possible to disable it temporarily? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find the device name with the command `ip link`, set it to down mode with `ip link set <device> down`. The device is most likely named something like wlp3s0. If operation isn't permitted, perform the command with `sudo`.

Comment: Is it possible to reenable it again with `ip link set <device> up`?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Answer (score 15):

Use rfkill:

```
$ rfkill block all
```

This will disable all wireless adapters, WiFi, Bluetooth, NFC, GPS, whatever your computer has built in. If you only want to disable one specific adapter, find out its ID with

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

In this example, the ID of the WiFi chip is `1`. Block it with

```
rfkill block 1
```

To reenable this interface, use

```
rfkill unblock 1
```

To reenable all interfaces use

```
rfkill unblock all
```

---

You can also choose to e.g. only disable all WiFi adapters and leave the rest by replacing `all` with `wifi`. Here's the full list of usable types from `man rfkill`:

```
block index|type
    Disable  the  device  corresponding  to the given index.  type is one of "all",
    "wifi", "wlan", "bluetooth", "uwb", "ultrawideband", "wimax", "wwan", "gps",
    "fm" or "nfc".
```

---

If you don't have `rfkill` installed, install it with

```
# pacman -S rfkill
```

PS: I have no idea why rfkill works when run as an unprivileged user. On my Mint, it doesn't have a `setuid` or `setgid` bit.