# How does rfkill work without being root (or using sudo)?

Tags: root, privileges

I saw this statement at the end of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256530/495409):

> PS: I have no idea why rfkill works when run as an unprivileged user. On my Mint, it doesn't have a setuid or setgid bit.

I was curious, and looked on my Arch system. Here's what `sudo` and `rfkill` look like on my system. File sizes and dates have been omitted. It looks like there's no setuid bit on `rfkill` (there is one on `sudo`, for comparison).

```bash
$ /usr/bin/env ls -lah $(which sudo) $(which rfkill)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root [OMITTED] /sbin/rfkill
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root [OMITTED] /sbin/sudo
```

Interestingly, running `rfkill` to disable & enable wireless access works [as described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/256530/495409), *even though I'm running `rfkill` from my account (i.e., not as `root` and not with `sudo` or similar)*.

How does `rfkill` not require `root`, as typically commands that enable/disable hardware need to be ran with `root` privileges?

Comment: Hint: `getfacl /dev/rfkill` while at the local keyboard.

Comment: @A.B I ran that, and one of the lines is `# group: rfkill` - looking at [this Arch Wiki section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/users_and_groups#User_groups), it states, "Right to control wireless devices power state (used by rfkill)" for the `rfkill` group. I'm not very familiar with groups, so I'm not sure how it being part of a group gives it that permission, but... am I on the right track with that?

Comment: @A.B Yep, I've accepted it. I totally forgot to earlier, thanks for the ping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern Linux system ecosystems, probably when *systemd* based, can change the access rights of `/dev` entries when physically logged (ie: in front of the keyboard).

One can compare the ownership of `/dev/rfkill`. Exemple here on a Debian 12 system when looking with user having UID 1000 logged in a local (physical) session:

```
$ echo $UID
1000
$ getfacl -n /dev/rfkill
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/rfkill
# owner: 0
# group: 106
user::rw-
user:1000:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

So here the extra ACL gives owner access rights to the device file:

```
user:1000:rw-
```

If not at the part where the user is physically logged in (the `sleep 5` gives the time to switch to a console with a login prompt), this ACL gets removed if it was present:

```shell
$ sleep 5; getfacl -n /dev/rfkill
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/rfkill
# owner: 0
# group: 106
user::rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

As long as the linked kernel driver doesn't specifically restrict further access rights or ownership beyond the ACL on the device file, this works for the application using it without additional privileges.

Running (as root would be better but the result doesn't really change):

```
inotifywait -m -r -e attrib /dev
```

and switching twice, to a console with a login prompt and back, to get an idea, it's usually also done for:

- audio-related files (`/dev/snd/`)
- video-related files (`/dev/dri/`)
- possibly some removable device files (eg: the target of `/dev/cdrom` ...)
- KVM for virtualization (`/dev/kvm`)
- probably other files I missed.

This might not reflect defaults, but gives an idea.

A quick search found this entry in *systemd* documentation's in [Multi-Seat on Linux](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/#udevrules):

> Note that **logind** manages **ACLs on a number of device classes**, to allow
> user code to access the device nodes attached to a seat **as long as the
> user has an active session on it**. This is mostly transparent to
> applications.

When this is managed using *systemd* at least two components play a role:

- *udevd* tags eligible devices appearing on the system with `TAG+="uaccess"`

  Empirically the list could be found with something like (systems that don't have `/lib` symlinked to `/usr/lib` should also search in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d`):

  ```
  grep -rw uaccess /etc/udev/rules.d /lib/udev/rules.d
  ```

  Among other results, one can find a line for rfkill in `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-uaccess.rules`:

  ```
  KERNEL=="rfkill", SUBSYSTEM=="misc", TAG+="uaccess"
  ```
- *logind* tracks user seat changes (of course in addition to creation) and changes ACLs for devices previously tagged with *uaccess* when the user seat is active

  For the little details: [`seat_set_active()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v255/src/login/logind-seat.c#L206) -> [`seat_apply_acls()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v255/src/login/logind-seat.c#L206) -> [`devnode_acl_all()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v255/src/shared/devnode-acl.c#L138), the later checks for the *uaccess* tag.

Comment: This is known as `uaccess`, and [isn’t well documented](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4288) (at least by the projects implementing it).