VIRSH sometimes does not support type KVM
Sometimes, my user cannot start guests although mostly it can.
Pardon the vagueness of sometimes/mostly, but I have no idea what happens inbetween, with the exception of the restart of the host machine. Later, without configuration in /etc or with virsh edit, is works.
host:~$ virsh start Lin0021
error: Failed to start domain 'Lin0021'
error: unsupported configuration: Emulator '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' does not support virt type 'kvm'

host:~$ kvm -m 4096 /srv/kvm/LinDeb0021/LinDeb0021_disk_0001.qcow 
Could not access KVM kernel module: Permission denied
kvm: failed to initialize kvm: Permission denied
kvm: falling back to tcg
gtk initialization failed
host:~$ 

The user is a member of libvirt.
host:~$ getfacl /dev/kvm 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/kvm
# owner: root
# group: kvm
user::rw-
user:user11:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

host:~$ 

root# getfacl /dev/kvm 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/kvm
# owner: root
# group: kvm
user::rw-
user:user11:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::---

root# 


What's the output of getfacl /dev/kvm?

Thank you for contributing. I've added the output.

Possibly (very) loosely related (the ACL user:lightdm:rw- hints it could be about systemd's seat and physical user permission): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769615/how-does-rfkill-work-without-being-root-or-using-sudo
